# How can I use a php array as a path to target a value in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to access a specific array's property by using a separate array as the path. The problem is the property in question may be at any depth. Here's an example...

I have the associative array of data:

```
$data = array(
    '1' => 'somethings_value',

    '2' => 'another_value',

    '3' => array(
        '1' => 'deeper_value',
    ),
);
```

Now I want to access one of these values but using another array that will dictate the path to them (through the keys). So say I had a path array like this:

```
$path = array('3', '1');
```

Using that `$path` array I would want to get to the value `$data[3][1]` (which would be the string `'deeper_value'`).

The problem is that the value to access may be at any depth, for example I could also get a path array like this:

```
$path = array('1');
```

Which would get the string value `'somethings_value'`. I hope the problem is clear now.

So the question is, how do I somehow loop though this path array in order to use its values as keys to target a value located in a target array?

Thanks!

EDIT: It might be worth noting that I have used numbers (albeit in quotes) as the keys for the data array for ease of reading, but the keys in my real problem are actually strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple loop should work:

Update: sorry did check my code

```
foreach($path as $id) 
{
    $data = $data[$id];
}

echo $data;
```

Result:

```
deeper_value
```

This will overwrite the `$data` array so you might want to make a copy of `$data` first like [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625808/how-can-i-use-a-php-array-as-a-path-to-target-a-value-in-another-array/6625891#6625891) did in his example.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to access `$data[3][1]` with this method.

Comment: I'm not sure of what I'm about to say, but are you sure that `foreach` will always take the `$id` in the correct order? That's not the case in Java, for example.

Comment: @Oltarus: I'm sure that php's arrays always have a well-defined order that foreach respects, and that the order defaults to the order of insertion... but I can't find a reference!

Comment: @grossvogel Ok, Big Bird, just checking!

Answer (score 3):

It's not the greatest code, but should work:

```
function getValue($pathArray, $data)
{
   $p = $data;
   foreach ($pathArray as $i)
   {
     $p = $p[$i];
   }

   return $p;
}
```

Comment: You can't access `$data` inside a function unless you use the `global` keyword. Since `global` is lame, you should pass `$data` as a function parameter, which also saves you from having to explicitly create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach:

```
while($d = array_shift($path))
    $data = $data[$d];
```